# How can I hide my page name and extension in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I hide my page name and extension in the address bar?

For example when I click on my "Home" link, it would take me to:

www.mysite.com/index.html

but instead I'd like it show in the address bar without the page name and extension, like this:

www.mysite.com/

Comment: If you are IIS default document is index.html, you can simply redirect to mysite.com, it won't show index.html. Alternative use MVC :) I don't think it is possible in Javascript

Comment: Can't you just make your link point to `"/"` instead of `"/index.html"`?

Comment: No ....I can't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you writing your "***Home***" link?

Having said that, don't include the `/index.html` portion in your **anchor tag**.

Also, if you wanted to show the main site URL `www.mysite.com` for every local link in your site no matter the webpage your at (photo gallery, about us, etc.), wrap your whole website in a **iframe** that's the entire space of the viewport which will prevent the **Address Bar** from changing.

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle or is it???**](http://jsfiddle.net/mCuUg/show/)

The above jsFiddle site shows this simple iframe method described. Notice that the Address Bar is always at the same place since the iframe is receiving all the navigation interaction.

View that jsFiddle without the `/show/` as seen in the **Address Bar** to access the **Edit Page**.

Answer (score 5):

this should work.

Put this in a file called .htaccess and put it in your root directory.
Only works on a apache webserver though and not locally.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* $0.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `.htaccess` file in your website's root directory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

When you've added the above file you can access the following url:

```
www.mysite.com/index.html
```

by using this url:

```
www.example.com/contactus
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
window.location.href = 'WHAT LOCATION YOU WANT';
```

But this will reload the page. You should find the solution on the server side.